# Could not extract ResultSet. Problem with Oracle Database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot connected with Oracle Database application. The same version of the application works fine with MySQL, but when I try to do some requests to Oracle Database it throws error:

`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause`

> "status":500,"error":"Internal Server
> Error","trace":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
> at com.example.pawel.expense.controller.ExpenseController.createExpense(ExpenseController.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
> ECT...

So here is my controller method for this function:

```
    @PostMapping("/expense")
    ResponseEntity<Expense> createExpense(@Valid @RequestBody Expense expense) throws URISyntaxException {

        Expense result = expenseRepository.save(expense);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/expense/" + result.getId())).body(result);
    }
```

And my **Expense** model

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="expense")
@Entity
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Instant date; 

    private double amount;
    
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

// Getters and setters
```

Here is my **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.server.compression.enabled=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Side note - do not use `system` as a connection user, create your own application connection user...

Comment: `SELECT 1` is not a valid query for Oracle - use `select * from dual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `Hibernate Dialect` to your ***application.properties*** like so

```html
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Or create a *Bean* for Oracle datasource. Follow this guide for further information
[Configuring Spring Boot for Oracle](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/)